# Run app phonegap with xcode on jailbroken iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, cordova, jailbreak

I developed an app with phonegap, and I hate to try on a apple device. I've jailbroken my iPhone5s for try my app without pay apple.

I follow this guide, but seems does't work:

> On your Jailbroken device install AppSync Unified 5.2-1 (or later)
>   from AngelXWind’s repo. Don’t use any other AppSync, and if you have
>   others, be sure to remove them. Open
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/SDKSettings.plist
>   and change AD_HOC_CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED to YES. You may need to
>   duplicate it to the desktop, change it, save it, then drag and drop
>   back into the original folder because OS X let you edit the file in
>   place. If XCode was running, restart XCode. Change your Project and
>   Target settings to “Ad Hoc Code Sign” in Build Settings Tell XCode to
>   run app on iPhone. At this point XCode will put app on your iDevice,
>   but can’t debug because it can’t attach to the process. The app will
>   start then close immediately. You can now manually start the app on
>   the phone now though. To enable debugging: In your project select
>   File>New File Property List and create a file called
>   “Entitlements.plist”. Add “Can be debugged” or “get-task-allow” (both
>   do the same thing) and set the value to YES. Now change your Project
>   and Target Code Signing Entitlements (In Build Settings) to
>   “Entitlements.plist” (you have to type it in). Now XCode can run and
>   debug the app. Good luck

[This](http://www.grobinson.me/developing-and-debugging-my-own-apps-on-jailbroken-ios8-1-using-xcode-6-1-without-paying-apple/) is the link of the guide.

When I run app, XCode tell me "Build Success", and on top it says :"Running  on Iphone". If I open detail, it say: "Preparing to install " with a loading circle. It's 20 minute that is preparing to install my app.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Seems like you're a bit confused, aren't you? To test your app, just run it from xcode to your none jailbroken iphone - **and (what a wonder) you don't have to pay for the installation** :O

Comment: I run my app from xcode to my jailbroken iphone. But on the top appear "preparing to install". It's 30 minutes that nothing happened

Comment: try xcode 7 beta, I think you can install the apps withouth paying

Comment: oneiros.altervista.org/jailcoder

Comment: jailcoder works only on xcode 3.x-4.x .. I have xcode 6

Comment: @jcesarmobile I try to install xcode7 beta, but I have the same problem..